# Enumerable.Any<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) should handle null enumerable too, surely?

Tags: .net, linq

Is there some pedantic Enumerator-theory-based reason why the Any() method throws an `ArgumentNullException` for a null enumerable?

I use IEnumerable wherever possible to pass collections of data around - but in most cases I then have this kind of code:

```
public class Foo
{
  public IEnumerable<IBar> Bars { get; set; }
}

////----

public static void UseAFoo(Foo foo)
{
  //if Bars has something in it, then do something:
  if(foo.Bars != null && foo.Bars.Any())
  {
    //blah
  }
}
```

Or,

```
if((foo.Bars ?? Enumerable.Empty<IBar>()).Any())
{
  //ugh!
}
```

Or modify the property declaration thus:

```
public class Foo
{
  private IEnumerable<IBar> _bars;
  public IEnumerable<IBar> Bars
  { 
    get { return _bars ?? Enumerable.Empty<IBar>(); }
    set { _bars = value; }
  }
}
```

Or the 'more efficient' way:

```
get { return _bars; }
set { _bars = value ?? Enumerable.Empty<IBar>(); }
```

In every case - it's nasty.  Okay so I can do my own extension method (which I have) - but naming is a bit tricky, because the best name is already taken!  I've gone for `NotNullAndAny()` but I don't like it.

`Any()` (and it's delegate-driven brother) should, in my opinion, return false if the Enumerable is null - it should not throw an `ArgumentNullException`.

But then like I say at the start - is there some hidden contract here that I'm missing?  Or is it just pedantry ;)

**UPDATE**

I had a feeling that the consensus was going to be that all linq extensions should throw `ArgumentNullException`, even the case of `Any()` - and to be honest while I feel that the case can still be made for `Any()`, the arguments for are not persuasive enough to overcome the basic fact that if an enumerable is null, no general operation can be completed satisfactorily for it and therefore an exception has to be thrown.

Thus I will go with an extra extension method `NotNullAndAny()` to clean up my code where nulls are reasonably possible (and not an error).  In cases where a null enumerable is not allowed I already throw `ArgumentNullException` too.  In some cases however it's more practical to allow consumers of my code to leave a property unset whilst equally not forcing my classes to require manually implemented properties or default constructors to make sure these properties don't ever get a `null`.  If that's my choice, then I consign my own code to have to check both null and empty.

Only thing now is which response to mark as the answer! :)

Comment: May be this post by Eric Lippert will be interesting to you: [Null Is Not Empty](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/14/null-is-not-empty.aspx)

Comment: Good post - thanks for the link. I totally get what he's saying there - but for me it doesn't quite seem to wash with the `Any` method. I've not had a scenario yet where I would treat a null enumerable different from an empty one where the `Any` method would cause me problems by handling nulls.

Comment: it's an extension method - you're free to implement your own version, and import it in preference to the Linq one. But now you're writing code that does "more magic" behind the scenes (hiding nulls), and won't be immediately familiar to someone who's used to Linq.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: yeah I don't like the idea of hiding Any() with my own one - so I'll stick with writing a `NotNullAndAny()` extension method instead.  Like the `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` static method the name clearly states that nulls are handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't answer whether there's a sound theoretical reason for it - but to me, we are dealing with two distinct concepts. I'll misuse language and talk about lists, rather than enums, but the same arguments should apply: There is a big difference between there being a list which contains no items, and the list not being present at all.

---

And personally, given your listed code options, I'd go with one you didn't list (if it makes sense to have a settable enumerable, and your class really can work with any enumerable):

```
public class Foo
{
  private IEnumerable<IBar> _bars = Enumerable.Empty<IBar>();;
  public IEnumerable<IBar> Bars
  { 
    get { return _bars;  }
    set {
        if(value==null) throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
         _bars = value;
    }
  }
}
```

i.e. Don't let nulls creep into *your* design if you don't want to deal with them

Comment: yeah this is true - most of my code has null checking on parameters etc everywhere and so I can see the argument for me having to do it - or indeed handle both nulls and empties myself.

I don't necessarily want to have to do the above for all my types as it means having to manually implement properties or implementing a default constructor manually too.  I want people to be able to get an instance of these classes and fill out the properties they want to set. +1 though - I can see that the consensus here is that nulls are still a special case even for Any()

Comment: @Andras - yes, I think generally what we're trying to get across is that *you* want to treat null and empty enumerables as equivalent, whereas some people want or need to treat them differently.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should not return `false` when parameter is `null`.

With this one throwing an exception for a `null` parameter matches up with general behavior of other `BCL` classes.

It does return `false` when the `sequence` is `empty`.

There is a difference between having a `null` value and having a parameter value as an `empty sequence` (which is a sequence with no elements in it).

Comment: yes but when an enumerable is null it by definition also can't have anything in it - therefore Any() should be false - not an exception.

Comment: That is what I am trying to explain. A variable with `null` value does not refer to any object in memory. When you don't have an object to use members of, you literally can't do anything. And on the other hand, having a `sequence`/`collection` with no items inside, is still a valid value. You can still use it's members because it exists.

Comment: mmm - that's a fair point.  I can see that every other extension method always must throw an `ArgumentNullException` for the exact reason you're saying. Just seems a bit pedantic to do it on Any() as well - since it's only confirming the existence of more than zero items. I know you can argue it can't determine this truth on a null reference - but sometimes common sense should be applied instead of black and white rules?

Answer (score 1):

Null in practice is often an incorrect state and is treated as such by the vast majority of APIs - the API for linq is following this. Perhaps you should question why you have null enumerables in the first place, and guard against this. A second approach would be to write your own extension methods that give you the desired behaviour. Excessive null checking (inside code rather than just parameter checking) is usually a code smell.